# How to customize the select element for our requirement or how to convert dropdown became validatable select component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular8

I am attached the custom select component from visual design. I need to reproduce it. up to my level I am not able to customize the `select` component to mach this mock.
But as a option, I can able to create a drop down using `ul` to match the same. But In my angular app, I am using Reactiveform, so, where I could not able to add the validation errors.

so what is the correct way to handle this kind of scenario?

[Mytry](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

here is my mock up:

[image: Custom Select]

Answer (score 0):

Using [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) you can set Validators to any of your Form Controls

```
public readonly form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    SelectedValue: new FormControl("",Validators.required)
});
```

Then in your template you can use any options you want defined in your component or otherwise, and set some flags and helpful messages when the form control is not valid.

`Validators.required` will make sure that the field is required for the `form` to be valid

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName="SelectedValue">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>
  </select>
  <h3 *ngIf="!form.controls.SelectedValue.valid">Selected Value field is required</h3>
  <button disabled="!form.controls.SelectedValue.valid" (click)="doSomething()"> Click me</button>
</div>
```

Your component (Do not forget the imports!):

```
****
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
****

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}
options = [{key:1,value:"A"},
           {key:2,value:"B"},
           {key:3,value:"C"}];

public readonly form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
   SelectedValue: new FormControl("",Validators.required)
});

doSomething(){
   //ur logic goes here
   alert(this.form.value.SelectedValue);
}
```

Another option is to use [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources)   if you are using angular bootstrap in your project which has some extra functionality like clear and styling.

Comment: I am looking for the answer to use `drop-down` instead of `select` element

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with the `drop-down` that cannot be achieved with `select`? You can take a look at [angular dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples). I am pretty sure you can still use reactive forms with it